# How to read log files with 70000 records each into a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, logging

EDIT2: the log seems a csv file with whitespace as a delimiter. I tried directly reading using csv-file reader. But the thing is all these files have 3-4 lines of description which I need to remove first. Tried manually deleting those rows, it worked. now the question is is there a way to skip reading those rows(tried skiprows, but it gives some character error as it should). i can try deleting those rows using open, but that seems a lot of work, writing 120 files. Is there a workaround?

EDIT1: It appears that the data might be missing values at some indices. The question remains how to read large log files into dataframe

So i have weblogs of 3 months, with each file being a 1 day weblog. Each file has around 70000 odd records/lines. How to read them into a single dataframe?

Here is what I tried so far:

```
log_data=open(path,'r')
result={}
j=0
for line in log_data:
  if j>3: #First three lines are comments and description
    columns = line.split(' ') 
    result[j-4] = {cats_list[i]: columns[i] for i in range(15)}
    # break

  j+=1
js=json.dumps(result)
df=pd.read_json(js, orient='index')
```

But i get `list index out of range` when j reaches 9998. Is this a memory restriction or something?
Here are the columns basically:

```
cats_list = ['date', 'time', 's-sitename', 's-ip', 'cs-method', 'cs-uri-stem', 'cs-uri-query', 's-port', 'cs-username', 'c-ip', 'cs(User-Agent)', 'cs(Referer)', 'sc-status', 'sc-substatus', 'sc-win32-status']
```

Comment: Doesn't seem like a memory issue so much as that you have a false assumption about what the file cotains. Memory might be an issue with what you are trying to do, but it wouldn't manifest like that.

Comment: @JohnColeman Yeah, i think the data is missing some values at certain indices

Comment: Either it is a csv file (perhaps with a different delimiter than a comma) or it isn't. If it is a csv file -- use a csv-file reader. If it isn't -- what does it even mean to load it into a dataframe? You might need to write a custom parser that can decide which values are missing where. Your question seems to be, how to read a large log file into a dataframe when the log file doesn't split into columns in a reliable way. If that is your question, you need to provide more details.

Comment: @JohnColeman it is a csv file with whitespace as a delimiter. I tried directly reading using csv-file reader. But the thing is all these files have 3-4 lines of description which I need to remove first. Tried manually deleting those rows, it worked. now the question is is there a way to skip reading those rows(tried skiprows, but it gives some character error as it should). i can try deleting those rows using `open`, but that seems a lot of work,  writing 120 files. Is there a workaround?